# android get adMob height

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

In order to adapt all layout when adMob appears, I am trying to get its height without success, height is always = 0! How to reach it? Thank you.

```
 /** Called when an ad is received. */
      @Override
      public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) 
      {  
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final android.view.ViewTreeObserver obs = adView.getViewTreeObserver();

        obs.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw () {

                int height = adView.getHeight();

                return true;
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call adView.getHeight() too soon, the function can return 0 wich is perfectly normal, cause it takes some time to show the ad.

If you implement AdListener and then override the

```
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1);
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0);
```

functions, and within that functions you should get height of the ad without any problems

Comment: class already implements AdListener and events are properly fired! However, adView.height = 0!